# Generate input fields dynamically according to parent input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, dynamically-generated

I have a simple HTML `input` field. When the user types a value that is not equal to `100` and clicks outside of the input field another input field appears with the value=100-user inserted value.

For example: if a user enters `40` in first input field and second input field shows `60`. If the first input field value is equals to `100` nothings happens. I'm achieving this by using simply adding and removing a CSS class with Javascript.

The problem is that I can't go for more than 2 levels, meaning that if the user enters `40` in first input field and second input field shows `60`, then if the user change that `60` to `30` another input field must appear with value of `30` and so on.

How can I achieve this using Javascript or jQuery?

```js
(function($) {
  var minNumber = 0;
  var maxNumber = 100;

  $(".dynamic-input").on("change", function() {
    var inputVal = parseFloat($(this).val().replace("%", "")) || 0;
    
    if (minNumber > inputVal) {
      inputVal = 0;
    } else if (maxNumber < inputVal) {
      inputVal = 100;
    }
    
    if (inputVal == 100) {
      var dyn_row = document.getElementById("dynamic-row");
      dyn_row.classList.add("dynamic-row-hidden");
    } else {
      var dyn_row = document.getElementById("dynamic-row");
      dyn_row.classList.remove("dynamic-row-hidden");

      var new_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
      var dynamic_input_get_val =
        document.getElementById("dynamic-input-get");
      dynamic_input_get_val.value = 100 - new_val + "%";
    }
    $(this).val(inputVal + "%");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dynamic-row-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="dynamic-input" class="dynamic-input dinput" required="required" type="text" />
<div id="dynamic-row" class="dynamic-row dynamic-row-hidden" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <div>
    <input id="dynamic-input-get" class="dynamic-input-get dinput" required="required" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant:

> ...then if the user change that `40` to `30` another input field must appear with value of 30 and so on

Based on the given description this should get you started:

```
var calculatedValue;

var dynamicInput = $('#dynamic-input');
dynamicInput.on('change', function() {
    var dynamicInputGet = $('#dynamic-input-get');
  
    if(dynamicInput.val() <= 100 && dynamicInput.val() >= 0) {
        if(!calculatedValue) {
            calculatedValue = 100 - dynamicInput.val();
            dynamicInputGet.val(calculatedValue);
        } else {
            dynamicInputGet.val(dynamicInputGet.val() - dynamicInput.val());
        }
    } else if(dynamicInput.val() < 0) {
          dynamicInput.val(0);
          dynamicInput.trigger('change');
    } else {
        dynamicInput.val(100); 
        dynamicInput.trigger('change');
    }
});
```